# phpMyAdmin can't run on CentOS 6.5 with PHP5.5.8

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin

I have a CentOS 6.5 x64 server running nginx 1.0.15, PHP (FPM/FastCGI) 5.5.8 and MySQL 5.5.35.

I've installed phpMyAdmin 4.1.5 and configured an nginx vhost with the html_root linked with a symlink to the directory of phpMyAdmin.

My problem is that when I open the address (`https://172.28.65.80:8060`) I get from phpMyAdmin this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 229
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

If I try to run phpMyAdmin from console using php (not php-fpm) it says:

```
# php /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/index.php

Warning: require(./libraries/Error_Handler.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php on line 57

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './libraries/Error_Handler.class.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php on line 57
```

obviously `Error_Handler.class.php` is correctly stored in `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/`

Edit2:

This is the configuration of the virtualhost used by phpMyAdmin:

```
#
# HTTPS phpmyadmin virtual host configuration
#

server {
    listen       8060;
    server_name  172.28.65.80;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /root/rootCA.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /root/rootCA.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
        index  index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         root           /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
         fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index  index.php;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Edit3:

These are the permissions of the phpMyAdmin files:

```
# ll
total 692
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1569 Jan 17 14:21 browse_foreigners.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  4829 Jan 17 14:21 changelog.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   308 Jan 17 14:21 chk_rel.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   852 Jan 17 14:21 composer.json
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 nginx nginx  4236 Jan 23 15:18 config.inc.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  4236 Jan 17 14:21 config.sample.inc.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  4178 Jan 17 14:21 db_create.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  8870 Jan 17 14:21 db_datadict.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   401 Jan 17 14:21 db_events.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2788 Jan 17 14:21 db_export.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   505 Jan 17 14:21 db_import.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  9297 Jan 17 14:21 db_operations.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  5269 Jan 17 14:21 db_printview.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1987 Jan 17 14:21 db_qbe.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   454 Jan 17 14:21 db_routines.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1636 Jan 17 14:21 db_search.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   872 Jan 17 14:21 db_sql.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  9465 Jan 17 14:21 db_structure.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  8277 Jan 17 14:21 db_tracking.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   364 Jan 17 14:21 db_triggers.php
drwxr-xr-x.  5 nginx nginx  4096 Jan 23 15:00 doc
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  3122 Jan 17 14:21 error_report.php
drwxr-xr-x.  2 nginx nginx  4096 Jan 23 15:00 examples
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx 37639 Jan 17 14:21 export.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx 18902 Jan 17 14:21 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2143 Jan 17 14:21 file_echo.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx 15581 Jan 17 14:21 gis_data_editor.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx 21171 Jan 17 14:21 import.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2679 Jan 17 14:21 import_status.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx 19846 Jan 17 14:21 index.php
drwxr-xr-x.  9 nginx nginx  4096 Jan 23 15:00 js
drwxr-xr-x. 13 nginx nginx 12288 Jan 23 15:00 libraries
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   728 Jan 17 14:21 license.php
drwxr-xr-x. 42 nginx nginx  4096 Jan 23 15:00 locale
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1988 Jan 17 14:21 navigation.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   389 Jan 17 14:21 phpinfo.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   746 Jan 17 14:21 phpmyadmin.css.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1808 Jan 17 14:21 phpunit.xml.nocoverage
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2051 Jan 17 14:21 pmd_display_field.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx 36692 Jan 17 14:21 pmd_general.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  5081 Jan 17 14:21 pmd_pdf.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  4560 Jan 17 14:21 pmd_relation_new.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2194 Jan 17 14:21 pmd_relation_upd.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2589 Jan 17 14:21 pmd_save_pos.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2594 Jan 17 14:21 prefs_forms.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx 14308 Jan 17 14:21 prefs_manage.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1213 Jan 17 14:21 print.css
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  6222 Jan 17 14:21 querywindow.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  4004 Jan 17 14:21 schema_edit.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1734 Jan 17 14:21 schema_export.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1075 Jan 17 14:21 server_binlog.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   735 Jan 17 14:21 server_collations.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2634 Jan 17 14:21 server_databases.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   615 Jan 17 14:21 server_engines.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   698 Jan 17 14:21 server_export.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   452 Jan 17 14:21 server_import.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1465 Jan 17 14:21 server_plugins.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx 11668 Jan 17 14:21 server_privileges.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2054 Jan 17 14:21 server_replication.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   577 Jan 17 14:21 server_sql.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   889 Jan 17 14:21 server_status_advisor.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  3538 Jan 17 14:21 server_status_monitor.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1369 Jan 17 14:21 server_status.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1663 Jan 17 14:21 server_status_queries.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1507 Jan 17 14:21 server_status_variables.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1625 Jan 17 14:21 server_user_groups.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1283 Jan 17 14:21 server_variables.php
drwxr-xr-x.  4 nginx nginx  4096 Jan 23 15:00 setup
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1039 Jan 17 14:21 show_config_errors.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  5507 Jan 17 14:21 sql.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  3474 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_addfield.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  5763 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_change.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  4400 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_chart.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2650 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_create.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2880 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_export.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1657 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_find_replace.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1334 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_get_field.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  3452 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_gis_visualization.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   590 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_import.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1205 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_indexes.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2828 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_move_copy.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx 12498 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_operations.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1474 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_printview.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  4616 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_relation.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx 13504 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_replace.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  3904 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_row_action.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  2175 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_select.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1014 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_sql.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  4577 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_structure.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  3927 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_tracking.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   144 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_triggers.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  5996 Jan 17 14:21 tbl_zoom_select.php
drwxr-xr-x.  4 nginx nginx  4096 Jan 23 15:00 themes
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   863 Jan 17 14:21 themes.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1348 Jan 17 14:21 transformation_overview.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  3961 Jan 17 14:21 transformation_wrapper.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   507 Jan 17 14:21 url.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  6883 Jan 17 14:21 user_password.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx   550 Jan 17 14:21 version_check.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  8914 Jan 17 14:21 view_create.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  3613 Jan 17 14:21 view_operations.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx nginx  1128 Jan 17 14:21 webapp.php
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243704/call-to-undefined-function-error-phpmyadmin

Comment: yes you're right, but there's not a solution there.

Comment: I have a centos 6.5 server running php 5.5.8 with no trouble at all...though I cannot remember how I installed it. sorry, with phpMyAdmin

Comment: Try using the latest version updated 4 days ago... http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/4.1.5/phpMyAdmin-4.1.5-all-languages.7z/download#!md5!025aa1ed84e4959bd6160a93515bc217

Comment: I've already the latest version.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed after I commented.

Comment: Is there a config.inc.php which is readable by the uid apache runs with?

Comment: I've not apache, I've nginx, by the way `config.inc.php` is readable by nginx: `-rwxr-xr-x.  1 nginx nginx  4236 Jan 15 14:09 config.inc.php`

Comment: are you using PhpMyAdmin and APC ?

Comment: No, APC is not enabled.

Comment: still idk if this can help I had the same error when APC was enabled and this link helped me maybe it can help you http://www.matteomattei.com/en/tag/tips-and-tricks/

Comment: Yes but I've said APC is not enabled...

Comment: Does it work w/o the symlink?

Comment: nope, even using the real path as path of the virtual host the problem is the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the solution.

The `/var/lib/php/session/` folder was not writeable by `nginx/php-fpm`, I've just edited the permissions to `777` and now it works.

Comment: I've just put 777 on my session folder but this not fix my issue :(

Comment: That completely saved the rest of my day!

Comment: even after i did all this it still showed me the same error - i was missing the `php-mbstring` - installed that and it works now

Comment: A1 Thanks, my httpd user and group is non standard. So I chown'ed the session folder to my httpd group.

Comment: better use: chgrp -R nginx /var/lib/php/session

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but I could solve this issue only when made chmod 755 to file `config.inc.php`

Comment: On CentOS 7, I solved this issue with a similar solution and changed group ownership of `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` from root to apache

Answer (score 0):

Make sure gettext is listed in `php -m` and if not install it.

Answer (score 0):

@Fez Vrasta

How did you do to install and get to run it... I'm dying in here...
I've tryed manually and nginx never got to see the files... and I've tryed almost everything.
symlinks, directly in root folder.

And If I try to install from the public repositories I get things like this at the end:

```
Error: Package: phpMyAdmin-4.1.6-1.el6.remi.noarch (remi)
       Requires: php-gmp
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.i686 (base)
           php-gmp
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.i686 (updates)
           php-gmp
       Available: php-common-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
           php-gmp
       Available: php-common-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
           php-gmp
       Installed: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.i686 (@remi-php55)
           Not found
Error: Package: php-tidy-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
       Requires: php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.24-1.el6.remi
       Installed: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.i686 (@remi-php55)
           php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.i686 (base)
           php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-26.el6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.i686 (updates)
           php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
       Available: php-common-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
           php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.23-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
           php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.24-1.el6.remi
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

===================================

My LEMP settings:

- Centos 6.5
- Php 5.5.8
- Nginx
- MySQL 5.1.71

===================================

Comment: `yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install phpMyAdmin` then apply my answer.

Comment: Finaly I got things running.

Here is what happened to me (it migth be usefull for someone).

The OS updated some libraries before the installation of the PhPMyadmin, part of the updates covered the PHP-FPM packages and the version newer version of the PHP has still some inconsistencies with the version of PhPMyAdmin I was installing.

The sollution?: Downgrade the PHP-FPM version and re-install the PhpMyAdmin.

Hope it helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

The /var/lib/php/session/ folder was not writeable by nginx/php-fpm, I've just edited the permissions to 777 and now it works.

This solution helped!