# PhpMyAdmin does not work with .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, phpmyadmin

PhpMyAdmin writes an error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './libraries/Error_Handler.class.php' (include_path='phpMyAdmin/libraries/') in /home/site.ru/lib/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php on line 64
```

correcting this error appear similar errors.
I think that the problem is in the lines .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I can not fix, help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin can't run on CentOS 6.5 with PHP5.5.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261825/phpmyadmin-cant-run-on-centos-6-5-with-php5-5-8)

Comment: I ran the same phpmyadmin without .htaccess on the same hosting and everything worked great

Comment: Then add an extra condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin` (if you access pma via `site.com/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Where is that .htaccess file coming from? What phpMyAdmin version do you have?

Comment: File .htaccess is in the root of the site. Version 4.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

- Click on Wamp Server icon(phpmyadmin)
- Select Apache
- Select Apache Modules
- Select rewrite_module
- Restart Your Wamp Server
- Run your program,if this not working there is problem with your .htaccess