# phpMyAdmin Fatal error: Call to undefined function __()

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Server running RHEL 7 and PHP 5.4.16.  When I try to open /phpMyAdmin in my browser, I'm given the error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 242`

```
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0008  348000  {main}( )   ../index.php:0
2   0.0018  503144  require_once( '/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php' )    ../index.php:12
3   0.0252  4224464 PMA_Config->__construct( )  ../common.inc.php:304
4   0.0252  4224712 PMA_Config->load( ) ../Config.class.php:100
5   0.0265  4309888 PMA_Config->checkConfigSource( )    ../Config.class.php:849
6   0.0265  4311088 PMA_fatalError( )   ../Config.class.php:1169
```

I believe I've installed all required libraries and that apache has the proper permissions for the session.save_path directory, which were the issues previous times that this question had been asked.  See: [Call to undefined function __() error - phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243704/call-to-undefined-function-error-phpmyadmin)

Can someone give me a hint based on that call stack?
Here are the functions from the lines that the stack trace references, with the relevant line written in the left margin:

`core.lib.php` at line 242:

```
   /**
   * displays the given error message on phpMyAdmin error page in foreign language,
   * ends script execution and closes session
   *
   * loads language file if not loaded already
   *
   * @param string       $error_message  the error message or named error message
   * @param string|array $message_args   arguments applied to $error_message
   * @param boolean      $delete_session whether to delete session cookie
   *
   * @return void
   */
   function PMA_fatalError(
       $error_message, $message_args = null, $delete_session = true
   ) {
   /* Use format string if applicable */
   if (is_string($message_args)) {
       $error_message = sprintf($error_message, $message_args);
   } elseif (is_array($message_args)) {
       $error_message = vsprintf($error_message, $message_args);
   }

   if ($GLOBALS['is_ajax_request']) {
       $response = PMA_Response::getInstance();
       $response->isSuccess(false);
       $response->addJSON('message', PMA_Message::error($error_message));
   } else {
       $error_message = strtr($error_message, array('<br />' => '[br]'));

       /* Load gettext for fatal errors */
       if (!function_exists('__')) {
           // It is possible that PMA_fatalError() is called before including
           // vendor_config.php which defines GETTEXT_INC. See bug #4557
           if (defined(GETTEXT_INC)) {
               include_once GETTEXT_INC;
           } else {
               include_once './libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc';
           }
       }

       // these variables are used in the included file libraries/error.inc.php
242    $error_header = __('Error');
       $lang = $GLOBALS['available_languages'][$GLOBALS['lang']][1];
       $dir = $GLOBALS['text_dir'];

       // on fatal errors it cannot hurt to always delete the current session
       if ($delete_session
           && isset($GLOBALS['session_name'])
           && isset($_COOKIE[$GLOBALS['session_name']])
       ) {
           $GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->removeCookie($GLOBALS['session_name']);
       }

       // Displays the error message
       include './libraries/error.inc.php';
    }
    if (! defined('TESTSUITE')) {
       exit;
   }
   }
```

`common.inc.php` at line 304:

```
304  $GLOBALS['PMA_Config'] = new PMA_Config(CONFIG_FILE);
     if (!defined('PMA_MINIMUM_COMMON')) {
         $GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->checkPmaAbsoluteUri();
     }
```

`Config.class.php` at line 100:

```
    /**
    * constructor
    *
    * @param string $source source to read config from
    */
   function __construct($source = null)
   {
       $this->settings = array();

       // functions need to refresh in case of config file changed goes in
       // PMA_Config::load()
100    $this->load($source);

       // other settings, independent from config file, comes in
       $this->checkSystem();

       $this->isHttps();

       $this->base_settings = $this->settings;
   }
```

`Config.class.php` at line 849:

```
    /**
    * loads configuration from $source, usually the config file
    * should be called on object creation
    *
    * @param string $source config file
    *
    * @return bool
    */
   function load($source = null)
   {
       $this->loadDefaults();

       if (null !== $source) {
           $this->setSource($source);
       }

       /**
        * We check and set the font size at this point, to make the font size
        * selector work also for users without a config.inc.php
        */
       $this->checkFontsize();

       if (! $this->checkConfigSource()) {
849       return false;
       }
```

`Config.class.php` at line 1169:

```
     /**
     * check config source
     *
     * @return boolean whether source is valid or not
     */
    function checkConfigSource()
    {
        if (! $this->getSource()) {
            // no configuration file set at all
            return false;
        }

        if (! file_exists($this->getSource())) {
            $this->source_mtime = 0;
            return false;
        }

        if (! is_readable($this->getSource())) {
            // manually check if file is readable
            // might be bug #3059806 Supporting running from CIFS/Samba shares

            $contents = false;
            $handle = @fopen($this->getSource(), 'r');
            if ($handle !== false) {
                $contents = @fread($handle, 1); // reading 1 byte is enough to test
                @fclose($handle);
            }
            if ($contents === false) {
                $this->source_mtime = 0;
                PMA_fatalError(
                    sprintf(
                        function_exists('__')
                        ? __('Existing configuration file (%s) is not readable.')
                        : 'Existing configuration file (%s) is not readable.',
                        $this->getSource()
                    )
1169            );
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: how abourt checking whar `core.lib.php on line 242` is

Comment: Updated post to include functions of lines referenced in the call stack.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was the wrong permissions for the `/etc/phpMyAdmin` directory.  The web server user, apache, had proper permissions for the `session.save_path` directory, but apache couldn't read from my config.inc.php file.  Changing the owner of /etc/phpMyAdmin to the apache user and changing the permissions to 755 solved the problem.

Looking at the `checkConfigSource()` function in `Config.class.php` led me to believe that if the problem was with accessing the configuration file then I would have received the error `'Existing configuration file (%s) is not readable.'` instead of `Call to undefined function __()`  Does anyone know why that wasn't the case?

This was a pretty basic problem/solution, but unless someone suggests otherwise I think I'll leave it up since this exact problem/solution isn't addressed in other discussions of the `Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/core.lib.php` error when trying to start phpMyAdmin after installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I had the same issue - using CenOS 7 with EPEL's phpmyadmin package (v4.9.3-1).
Changing the rights of /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php to 644 did the trick

Comment: Thanks a lot!    I had the same problem under CentOS 7.5.1804

Answer (score 4):

Had  the  same Error  message  from  phpMyAdmin  :: 
    *FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 245" while reading response header from upstream, client:*

Solution  that  worked  on  my  Fedora  22  server  x86_64  using  nginx    :
    changing  the  owner  and the group identifier   from  root:apache  on  the   file  /var/lib/php/session
   to  root:nginx
  using the  command  `sudo  chown  -Rfv  root:nginx /var/lib/php/session`.

Answer (score 2):

If phpmyadmin was working fine and then suddenly stops working for no reason with a bizarre and useless error message, you might try deleting your php sessions.

```
rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions/*
```

The exact location may very depending on OS and version, and this will delete all active sessions, not just yours, but it can fix some "suddenly stopped working" issues when you haven't changed anything and it was working fine before.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was different issue. I had given 777 permissions to phpMyAdmin forlder. When I changed it to 755, it worked fine.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score -2):

> Error "The connection was reset"
>  File:
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php

**search:**

```
$GLOBALS['PMA_Config'] = new PMA_Config(CONFIG_FILE);<br>
```

**replace with:**

```
$GLOBALS['PMA_Config'] = new PMA_Config();
```

Comment: Your answer is not very understandable