# Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in phpMyAdmin\libraries\Util.class.php on line 3162

Tags: phpmyadmin

I use XAMP V3.2.1, every thing was working well until I change all table COLLATION in my database and then refresh the data base but I got this message:

"**Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Util.class.php on line 3162**"

when accessing phpMyadmin at the end of the page after all records of my entries in tables...
So now whats the solution?

and I'm wondering if I add this data base to the real host this problem will happens to the phpMyAdmin of my host?

Comment: Hmm, looks like something went wrong internally, possibly a permissions problem or a garbled session. See the duplicates: [Call to undefined function \_\_() error - phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243704/call-to-undefined-function-error-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537617/phpmyadmin-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function

Comment: thank you , but those solutions didn't work for my problem ... I change all collation in  the back up file of database an reinstalled xampp . problem solved.