# phpmyadmin error with sanitizing.lib.php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having a problem getting phpmyadmin to work correctly on my desktop. Every time I try running phpmyadmin, I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\sanitizing.lib.php on line 135

I was wondering if anyone has advise on how to make phpmyadmin work correctly. I have Apache v2.4.1.8, php v5.5.33, and phpMAdmin v4.6.0 installed and according to the tutorials I followed, everything works correctly until I get to the phpMyAdmin.

If you need any other info, I will reply what I can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin Fatal error: Call to undefined function \_\_()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537617/phpmyadmin-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function)

Comment: Do you really need to create another question about the same subject? [Answers to other questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=Call+to+undefined+function+__()) really didn't help you to solve your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function \_\_() error - phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243704/call-to-undefined-function-error-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions error.

**You need to**

- Go into `php.ini` file and make sure `extension=mbstring.dll` is enabled.
- Restart your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

In the newest php versions the "extension_dir" path is not enabled initial. So maybe it helps... :)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWHqg.png)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making sure extension=mbstring.dll is enabled, you should make sure the extension path is correct.
By default, the extension path is set "/ext" in the php.ini file.
However, when install httpd as a service, the relative path may be incorrect.
So, you should edit the extension path to an absolute path, such as "C:\Program Files\PHP\v5.6.21\ext".