# Unable to install phpmyadmin on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm working on developing a web portal for Data visualization using PHP & google charts. 
I have installed `Apache`, `Php` and `Mysql` on **windows server 2012 r2** but unable to install **phpmyadmin**.

I have put PHPMyAdmin folder to my root directory and give this url in my browser: localhost/PHPMyAdmin

I get following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function __() in C:\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\sanitizing.lib.php:135 

Stack trace: 
#0 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Message.php(586): PMA_sanitize('session_start()...', false, true) 
#1 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Message.php(650): PMA\libraries\Message::decodeBB('session_start()...') 
#2 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Error.php(167): PMA\libraries\Message->getMessage() 
#3 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\ErrorHandler.php(157): PMA\libraries\Error->getHash() 
#4 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\ErrorHandler.php(121): PMA\libraries\ErrorHandler->addError('session_start()...', 2, 'C:\\Apache\\htdoc...', 83, true) 
#5 [internal function]: PMA\libraries\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'session_start()...', 'C:\\Apache\\htdoc...', 83, Array) 
#6 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\session.inc.php(83): session_start() 
#7 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php(266): require('C:\\Apache\\htdoc...') 
#8 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\inde in C:\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\sanitizing.lib.php on line 135
```

Comment: Please edit format you question, at the moment it's just a huge wall of text that makes me want to leave instantly ....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237930/phpmyadmin-error-with-sanitizing-lib-php

Comment: Any query that you may wanna ask ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your session directory is writable by the web server process.

The best way to do so is to create your own Phpinfo file; in any web accessible folder create a file (you can call it test.php or phpinfo.php or whatever you'd like) with the following content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Open that file in your browser (http://localhost/test.php or similar) and look for the line session.save_path. That's your session folder; make sure the permissions are suitable and see if that helps.

Like on windows right click that folder mentioned and look into properties where one can change the permissions.