# cannot run phpMyAdmin on Windows 10 - session.save_path issue?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have installed mysql, php5 and apache on windows 10 and I downloaded phpMyAdmin but when I try to open it from localhost/phpmyadmin I get the error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in C:\apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\sanitizing.lib.php on line 135

which I don't understand.

In one of other threads I found an information this may be caused by `session.save_path` being wrongly configured and when I open `phpinfo()` in the row with this variable there is no value in neither of the columns.

Apache is up and running and php is working and so is mysql. What could be the issue?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: check the correct answer from this post:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537617/phpmyadmin-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function

Comment: I believe the post you mentioned is about installing phpmyadmin on ubuntu. In my case there is no issue with permissions. I'm not sure how I could apply the answer from that thread to my problem.

Comment: I didn't see anywhere Ubuntu mentioned. Also i am talking about marked answer with 6 vote-up

Comment: In the answer it is said about changing permission in /etc/phpMyAdmin - this is where you find phpMyAdmin installed on Ubuntu which I did before. In my case I threw the phpmyadmin folder int C:/apache24/htdocs as this was the guidance in one of the tutorials I used for the installation. But I may be wrong. Still not sure how to apply the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get your problem solved, you could try using this program for hosting your website on your localhost. I'm using it all day long and haven't got any problems with that, yet.

https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html