# Call to undefined function, other

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I try to access our phpMyAdmin page it is now blank, worked fine before and not sure what has happened.

I get this error:

PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/Error_Handler.class.php on line 66

This is line 66 in that file:

```
$error = new PMA_Error(0, __('Too many error messages, some are not displayed.'), __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Comment: Not sure either, when I try to understand, I see a message that doesn't help at all.
Did you tweaked any piece of code? Can we see the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243704/call-to-undefined-function-error-phpmyadmin?rq=1