# phpmyadmin on NGINX with Centos7 shows blank white page?

Tags: mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, centos7

I am using Nginx with Centos 7 which is working fine.

After that I installed phpMyAdmin which was successfully installed as well, however when I access it on the browser it shows white blank page with no HTML source code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does error_log say?

Comment: nothing just blank page

Comment: I doubt the error log is a blank page

Comment: 2016/04/01 02:32:07 [error] 9943#0: *56 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in
/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 245" while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX, server:
XXX.XX.XXX.XXX, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "XXX.XX.XXX.XXX"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function \_\_() error - phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243704/call-to-undefined-function-error-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

The /var/lib/php/session/ folder was not writeable by nginx/php-fpm, I've just edited the permissions to 777 and now it works.

Answer (score 6):

based on the accepted answer I found the solution, But instead of changing the permission to `777` I prefer changing the ownership like below:

```
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/session/
```

The group of the `session` directory is `apache` by default, I changed it to `nginx` which is the user that runs `php-fpm` and `nginx`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a symlink

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /usr/share/nginx/html
```

After that, restart your php-fpm process.

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-a-centos-7-server