# Raspberry Pi phpmyadmin 500 Error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi3

Hello I have a problem with my Raspberry Pi - Apache2 - Phpmyadmin

If I view my phpmyadmin-dashbord the Server return a 500 error.

The Apache2 ErrorLog show this code.

`[Sat May 05 15:54:22.843993 2018] [:error] [pid 23131] [client 37.138.229.55:50419] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/core.lib.php:235\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/core.lib.php(308): PMA_fatalError('The [a@./url.ph...')\n#1 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(90): PMA_warnMissingExtension('mbstring', true)\n#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(12): require_once('/usr/share/phpm...')\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 235`

PDO and Mysqli is running.
Just the Dashbord is not avaible and return "500".

Thanks you for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function \_\_() error - phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243704/call-to-undefined-function-error-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the Problem.

I have upgrade from php5 to php7.0 and some files get lost

To run the following Code fixed the Problem

`sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext`

then restart your server

`sudo service apache2 restart`